# Poisson Distribution - Practical application - Time frame variance

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Goal of this question is to understand the variance of the lamba in the poisson distribution if the time frame varies. It is something I have to understand for my probability and statistics class. Question states that that by a Poisson process, you obtain 6 dysfunctional articles in 25 minutes. Question is if you consider X the number of dysfunctional articles produced in 5 minutes. Give the Poisson distribution for this event. Answer is Poi(1,2). How do I obtain it?

P.S. If the answer is bothering you then please ignore it. All I want is to get understand as to how to proceed to solve this kind of questions.

Comment: What does $\textrm{Poi}(1,2)$ mean in this context? Usually the poisson distribution is denoted as $\textrm{Poi}(\lambda)$. Or do you mean $\textrm{Poi}(1.2)$? Give a reply if you don´t want that the question will be closed.

Comment: I am writing the answer from the book. I have no clue as to what it means. My guess is lambda equals 2 and the time frame equals 1 for 1 period of 5 minutes

Comment: But the apparent rate of the process is $6/5$ if the unit of time is 5 minutes, not 2. Presumably your references have defined this notation for Poi(x,y) before...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the textbook is french and I forgot people in french denote the . as the ,. You have answered my question